# How to find all shared libraries actually used during execution in Linux?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

I have an executable and I would like to find out which shared libraries were actually used during a specific run. I know ldd would list all the shared library dependencies of that executable but I would like to find out the subset of those that were actually used during a specific run*. Is this possible?

*what I mean with specific run is running the executable with certain input parameters that would cause only a small part of the code to be run.

Comment: `part of the code to be run.` wait. Are you talking about the program doing `dlopen` a shared library by itself instead of the linker or are you interested in a callgraph of the library, where each function is tied to it's origin in a shared library?

Comment: An example of what I want is the following: let's say my program does the following: If input value is 1 call function A that is in shared library a.so and if input is 2 call function B that is in shared library b.so. I would like to run the program with input 2 and somehow get the information that b.so was used. At first glance I think Daniel's answer would do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ltrace(1)` for this:

```
$ PROG='ls -l'
# Collect call info
$ ltrace -o calls.txt -l '*' $PROG &> /dev/null
# Analyze collected data
$ cat calls.txt | sed -ne '/->/{ s/^\(.*\)->.*/\1/; p }' | sort -u
libacl.so.1
libcap.so.2
libc.so.6
libselinux.so.1
ls
# Compare with ldd
$ ldd /bin/ls | wc -l
10
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `strace` and grep for open .so files.

`strace $MYPROG  | grep -E '^open*\.so`

`lsof` also should work to grep for open libraries.

`lsof -p $PID | awk '{print $9}' | grep '\.so'`

This assumes the shared libraries have .so extension

Comment: The OP is asking about libs which are actually used (not simply loaded).